# How warp drive could be faster than light?

Tags: general-relativity, faster-than-light, warp-drives

If the speed of gravity is as fast as the speed of light then there is no way a warp drive could curve the fabric of spacetime faster than the speed of light. Then how does a warp drive actually make a spaceship go faster than light?

[image]

You see? If this bubble could curve spacetime, then it would never reach the speed of light, because curvature in front will not match the speed of the bubble.

Comment: An Alcubierre drive has superluminal *global* velocity. Only *local* velocity can't be superluminal.

Comment: @J.G. Superluminal motion means apparent speed, correct? So does the alcubierre bubble only "seem" to be faster than light?

Comment: That diagram(!) is a 2d field plot with a 3d "spaceship" superimposed, and not even on the plane of symmetry.  Who comes up with these ridiculous "visualizations"?

Comment: @CharlesTucker3 What do you mean by "apparent"? Suppose I point a laser at the Moon, swishing my wrist fast enough the image on the Moon's surface moves faster than $c$. The image's speed is global; my wrist's speed is local. You can measure both. Which is "apparent"?

Comment: Maybe worth noting that Alcubierre himself does not take this idea seriously. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGBMf-U-uD0

Comment: @J.G. The terms global and local superluminal speed were new for me, just looked in Wikipedia. If I get you right, the speed of the alcubierre bubble is like the speed of the image in your moon example? (Not restricted to c because not a real movement of any partical or so)?

Comment: The trick in Alcubierre drive is in changing space-time geometry by presence of a negative mass (energy). This altered space-time allow the warp bubble to move faster than light. Check Alcubierre paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0009013) for a formula for metric of the altered space.